# PDO FetchAll Fetch_Class not returning all rows/objects

Tags: php, pdo, kohana

When using `PDO::FetchAll()` in association with `PDO::Fetch_Class` i don't get all objects back. Just one object out of 5 or 6.

example:

`$as_object = 'Model_Menu'; $params = NULL;`

`$result->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, $as_object, $params);`

`$result = $result->fetchAll();`

But using 
`$result->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` gives me all the rows in the database.

Im using Kohana so i cant really show you the whole build of the query itself. But trust me it works, if fetch assoc does get all the result with the same build it should work right?

Environment :

```
-Linux ubuntu
-Driver: pdo/mssql/?ORM?
-Framework: Kohana
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps, because you're passing a third argument (`$params`, which is null), `PDO` assumes the fetchmode to be `PDO::FETCH_CLASS | PDO::FETCH_INTO`, re-assigning `$params` over and over. Remember that `PDO::FETCH_CLASS` will ***not*** call the constructor until *after* all properties are set. To call the constructor first, you need to set the fetch mode to `PDO::FETCH_CLASS | PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE`. Id' git this a bash:

```
$result->setFetchMode(
    PDO::FETCH_CLASS | PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE,
    $asObject
);
$objects = $result->fetchAll();
```

Looking at the docs, I've also noticed that most examples look like this:

```
$stmt->execute(); //<-- execute
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'ClassName');//pass fethcMode upon fetching
```